# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' between Ionic and Laravel

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, http-headers

I am currently building a Ionic Application, using laravel framework for the website. The problem is the following : I got

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

when I try to get json file from my API. I saw that it is an header problem and I need to authorize Access-Control-Allow-Origin. And I did it
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

When i refresh my page, I see with F12 menu on Chrome :

```
Response headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So, that means that the access is authorized. But when i try to access the link

> mywebsite.com/api

from the application, I still have the error *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

If some experts knows how to fix this issue.

Comment: Check this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: @HCK I already tried this and still do the same problem

Comment: Did you configured properly or just installed it?

Comment: I configured it properly, but I found the problem. It was a problem with my .htaccess . Thank you anyway !

Comment: Glad you found a solution. PS: Try share it in the answer section, it will be helpful to other people too ;) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my solution if someone is in the same case as me. The problem came from the .htaccess, I had login and password to access to the domain, and it blocked the ionic application, just desactivate them (No others solutions works).

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from @asamarcos (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/243) :

You have to register HandleCors on Kernel.php as requested in laravel-cors manual. This will add cors in all routes under the 'api' middleware.

```
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
```

Problem is Passport has it's own routes, outside of the API middleware.
So you have to set your passport routes on AuthServiceProvider explicitly giving HandleCors as a middleware:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes(null, ['middleware' => [ \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class ]]);
}
```